# I am getting some extra message when i call my php file from android app

Tags: php, android, remote-server

I have just started connecting android app with php
My file works very fine when i run on local wamp server
After uploading on remote server , I am getting what i want but i am getting some extra code on my emulator. I want to get rid of it
Please help.
When i call the same file in my chrome using an html file then also it works fine.

Here is code of my android app

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

HttpClient hc;
HttpPost hp;
List<NameValuePair> nvp;
HttpResponse hr;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    final  EditText password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    final  TextView res=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // String result="Username: "+username.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Password: "+password.getText().toString(); 
            //res.setText(result);
            try
            {
                hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
                hp=new HttpPost("http://pratik30.host56.com/insertquery.php");
                nvp=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nvp.add(newBasicNameValuePair("username", username.getText().toString()));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));
                hp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
                //hr=hc.execute(hp);
                ResponseHandler<String> rs= new BasicResponseHandler();
                String r=hc.execute(hp,rs);
                res.setText(r);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                res.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());   
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is the php file

```
<?php
    $dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','mypassword','pratik') or die('Error connecting to mysql server');
    $user=$_POST['username'];
    $pass=$_POST['password'];
    echo $user;
    echo $pass;
    $query = "Insert into users values ('$user','$pass');";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Error querying database');
    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

[Here is a picture](http://pratik30.host56.com/output.bmp) of the output I am getting.

Comment: Please take a read on SQL injection. (Can this comment be automatically posted on each php+mysql question from users with 1 rep?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php  returns the following you have to remove it  from there:

```
<!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>

<noscript><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/"><img src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php" alt="web hosting" /></a></noscript>

<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

you're setting the whole result text into your 
TextView `res.setText(r);`

---

hope it helps.

Comment: but i havn't returned all that in my php.

Comment: @user865075 then your host does that.

Comment: And no such thing comes when i run the script on localhost.The problem arises when i have uploaded on remote server. This thing doesn't comes up when i run the same script through this html file http://pratik30.host56.com/usernamepass.html

Comment: it's not you but your hosting provider. read here http://www.000webhost.com/forum/announcements/2160-disabling-analytics-code.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its very fine now